# Can the concept of optical étendue apply to sources at infinity?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

The general expression of [optical étendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) is:

$$dG = n^2 \, dS \, cos \theta \, d\Omega$$

Can the concept of optical étendue be reduced to a useful expression when considering a source at infinity (an ideal collimated beam with parallel rays, ignoring diffraction limits)?

My intuition is that the solid angle $d\Omega$ *could* reduce to something like a Dirac distribution, and the following expression can be used:

$$dG = n^2 \, dS \, cos \theta$$

Does that make sense?